# override mapping for a specific Entity class

Tags: symfony, doctrine-orm, doctrine, doctrine-mapping

I'm using a standard Symfony 2.8 framework with Doctrine.
My entities' mappings are all annotated, but I would need to map a single entity by using the PHP way (by defining `loadMetadata` static method) . I know there's a way to override a mapping Bundle configuration like explained [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8940662/is-there-a-way-to-modify-the-entity-mapping-configuration-for-doctrine-outside-t), but what I would like is specifying a single Entity. Is that possible? Thanks

Comment: What is the use case for this? Maybe their is another way to solve the problem

Answer (score 1):

No you can't mix the formats

```
A bundle can accept only one metadata definition format. For example, it's not possible to mix YAML metadata definitions with annotated PHP entity class definitions.
```

see doc here:
http://symfony.com/doc/current/doctrine.html

if you really need to change the mapping format then I suggest you create a new bundle for your specific entity. I also had this problem. I wished to have different mapping format (yml and annotation in my case) but I had to create a new bundle.